# Banner doesnt show on the screen only graph

Tags: android

I have one problem if i use this code i cant see google AdView i dont know where is it :( Whatever i make it wasnt show but the banner in first page working good but this in second not :( Can anyoune suggest me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />

<com.calculator.grap.GraphPanel
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: terrible grammar. difficult to understand your doubt.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a vertical layout it show on the top.Moreover you should not be using match_parent for both width and height of AdView.
You should use height as 0dp if you are using layout_weight.

Change the height of GraphPanel to 0dp.

Also rephrase your question in a better way.